# How many users *actually* land on the homepage?

Tags: website-design, e-commerce, homepage, seo

A bit of an off-UX question but I think it still relates.

I've been designing a few e-commerce websites now and there is always a lot of talk about the homepage, what to include for first time users, etc.

But honestly speaking, for an online-shop, don't most users stumble upon it through search engines that then suggest them their product? So most user's first contact with an online-shop will be the product detail page (my assumption).

[Baymard.com writes](https://baymard.com/blog/ecommerce-homepage-ux)

> The homepage remains **the “front door”** for the many users who still begin their browsing experience here.
> However, in testing we also observed it to act as a **navigational anchor** and a “safe” fallback.

But I am left to wonder if so many people actually begin their experience there.

**So the UX part of my question is:** What type of target user group should a home page even be geared towards? Maybe first time users who want to check out what shop/brand this is after landing on a PDP through a search engine link?

Comment: It seems it is a broadly discussed question, so *currently* the main aim is to define several target groups and their preferences (or expectations). Is it so ?   Explain additionally, please, if I misunderstood the idea

Comment: @TomNewton Yes I think that fits. The target group(s) and their needs/expectations.

Comment: If so, the question becomes a bit of marketing sense, so tag #e-commerce is quite good for attracting the attention of such visitors and searchers. It might be a good idea to look for some **marketing research** which can include the statistics of polls.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find one of two strategies that are commonly employed on home pages, depending on your particular marketing and advertising strategy (of which Google Search or Social Media marketing will be among them).

The first is to create a home page specifically for conversion, so the focus will be on a single flow that will lead to a direct call-to-action. This could actually be the first and only thing that user sees.

The second is to create a 'landing page' that can take the user on different paths depending on the channel that they are being directed from. You'll see this commonly in home pages that have a few different sections with different functions (e.g. search, list, carousel, etc.)

But the point is that it is not possible to answer this question because different sites have their different approaches and strategies, so you just have to customize it for optimum conversion and/or best user experience.